# Django External Database Read Only , Display on Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to start a simple django app. I have been on it for days. I was able to this in flask in a few hrs.

I need advice on connecting to an external database to grab tables and display them on django pages.

This is my code in flask

```
@app.route("/topgroups")
def topgroups():
    con = sql.connect("C:\\Users\\win10\\YandexDisk\\apps\\flask\\new_file.sqlite")
    con.row_factory = sql.Row

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT domain, whois, Traffic, Groups,LE,adddate FROM do_1 where Groups in (75,86,66,58,67,57,68,85,48,56,76,77,46,65,47,64,45,55,74,54,44,33,34,43)")
    rows = cur.fetchall();

    return render_template("index.html", rows = rows)
```

Comment: Official django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the python answer but read until the end because you may be losing a lot on Django if you follow this approach.

Python comes with SQLite capabilities so you don't even need to install packages [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

**Connect**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\win10\\YandexDisk\\apps\\flask\\new_file.sqlite')
```

Want to ensure read only? from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect)

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('file:C:\\Users\\win10\\YandexDisk\\apps\\flask\\new_file.sqlite?mode=ro', uri=True)
```

**Use**

```
cur = conn.cursor()
... (just like for flask)
```

**Note/ My recommendation**

One of the biggest advantages of Django is:

> Deﬁne your data models entirely in Python. You get a rich, dynamic database-access API for free — but you can still write SQL if needed.

And you'll loose a lot without it, from basic stuff like what you asked to even unit-testing capabilities.

Follow this tutorial to integrate your database: [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/).

> You may set `manage=False` and Django won't touch in those tables,
>   only create new ones to support the app.

If you just use that DB for some special purpose then give a look at [Django Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/)